# how to serialize/deserialize data in windows ce 5.0

Tags: windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

I am creating a program for a bar-code reader CHD FIVE running Windows CE 5.0.
i have a file containing a csv table output with item bar-codes(approx 94000 rows). It is 8MB in size. I can go through the file at every program startup but that is long. Maybe if i would serialize the data and after deserialization i get a DataTable. In what way could i do this? or any other ideas where a table such as this needs to be quickly accessible and searchable offline. i have searched for solutions bet havent found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would first sort the data and then use a quick search algorithm. You can create a parallel table with only the index and do the search on this table. You can also use a entropy minimization algorithm to create a new and simple index set.